# Xamarin Forms, change application name on Android

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Forms to develop a mobile application for Android. I would like to customize application name, but I'm having some troubles, since the expected label isn't shown everywhere.

I changed Application name in Android Manifest configuration page, but this label is only shown during application install and when I look in Settings > Applications.
If I go in application's list or even if I tap on application's list icon, a wrong label is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a48eeb0d-88e1-426a-80e9-d1f1981ff458/how-to-change-the-name-of-appin-the-screen-under-the-icon?forum=xamarinforms) forum, as answered by User277265: the displayed name is defined in your activity with the tag "MainLauncher = true".